# Converting Prototype to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Converting "new Form.getElements(window.document.forms[0]) " Prototype to jQuery

I am trying to convert a javascript code to jQuery which has some prototype.js codes

Please help me to find a best solution in converting this.

```
   function init() {

   var arr = new Form.getElements(window.document.forms[0]);
   var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
   for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) { // Append ULs with a questionId attrib to the list
   var obj = list[i].getAttribute("questionid");
   if (list[i].getAttribute("questionid")) {
    arr[arr.length] = list[i];
   }
   }

   arr.each(function(element) {
   var dependsOn = element.getAttribute('dependson');
   if (dependsOn && $(dependsOn)) {        
   new Form.Element.EventObserver($(dependsOn), function() { 
   populateQuestionOptions(element); });
  }
});
}
```

The doubt in finding an equivalent of new Form.getElements(window.document.forms[0]) in

jQuery or javascript and new Form.getElements(window.document.forms[0]).

The code I tried

```
function init() {
  var arr = jQuery('form');
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 

      var obj = list[i].getAttribute("questionid");
      if (list[i].getAttribute("questionid")) {
        arr[arr.length] = list[i];
      }
    }

      arr.each(function(element) {
      var dependsOn = element.getAttribute('dependson');
      if (dependsOn && jQuery('#dependsOn')) {         
        jQuery('#theForm').bind(jQuery('#dependsOn'),function() {     
        populateQuestionOptions(element); }; 

      }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Just asking on StackOverflow without even trying anything on your own is definitely _not_ the best way.

Comment: My apologies for not adding the code i tried. I have edited the question.

Comment: See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074447/how-can-convert-jquery-code-to-prototype-code

Comment: @vcrzy I am looking for Prototype to jQuery

Comment: I'm not familiar with how prototype works, so can you explain what the code does? That would help in determining what jquery/js code would be needed to duplicate the functionality.